# Subtract following row/rows with conditions from the previous row/rows in order to calculate cashflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I am trying to make calculations that has a specific subtraction case, which I will be using in a view. In order to explain clearly I am going to give my table sample:

| Date | Name | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.02.2024 | A | Credit | 50 |
| 13.02.2024 | A | Credit | 70 |
| 21.03.2024 | B | Credit | 30 |
| 01.04.2024 | A | Cash | 100 |
| 10.07.2024 | A | Cash | 10 |
| 19.07.2024 | B | Credit | 80 |
| 30.07.2024 | B | Cash | 150 |

I have date, customer name, type of the payment and amount of the paymet in each row and I have multiple customers. There are scheduled payments to be made in the promised dates; the type of the payment is "credit". The customer comes in and gives a check (which is the "cash" type) to be cashed on another date.

For example customer A has credit payments that are scheduled to 11.02.2024 with the amount of 50 $ and another one scheduled to 13.02.2024 with the amount of 70 $. Instead of paying them on the the scheduled time, customer gaves me a check for me to cash in 21.03.2024. I need to subtract this amount from the credits, starting from the first credit than moving on to the next. In this way I am updating the cash flow. Another example is given for the customer B as well. Here is the output that I want to have:

| Date | Name | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.02.2024 | A | Credit | 0 |
| 13.02.2024 | A | Credit | 20 |
| 21.03.2024 | B | Credit | 0 |
| 01.04.2024 | A | Cash | 0 |
| 10.07.2024 | A | Cash | 10 |
| 19.07.2024 | B | Credit | 0 |
| 30.07.2024 | B | Cash | 40 |

I have other types of payments in my table as well, but I want the calculation only between these two types. Also, I don't want the amount to be negative when the "cash" amount is subtracted.

I have tried using `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions as well as other methods to find the next record with the type 'cash' and to subtract them from each other, but I wasn't succesful. How can I achieve this?

To be honest, I  felt like I am going in a wrong way since my goal is not directly related to the 'next row'. In fact, mostly the rows are not in an order as provided in the sample table (with more different types of payments that are not related to the calculation.).How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you don't actually identify your customers by name in the table and instead have some sort of ID field. Cause you can call me Smith, John Smith.

With that being said, this operation usually requires some kind of loop.
I think it's probably easier/less cluttered to do with nested cursors, but I'm going to demonstrate with a recursive CTE monstrosity:

```sql
DROP TABLE #t
DROP TABLE #transactionLog
SELECT  *
,   CAST(0 AS INT) AS AmountLeft
INTO    #t
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1,N'2024-02-11', N'A', N'Credit', 50)
    ,   (2,N'2024-02-11', N'A', N'Credit', 30)
    ,   (3,N'2024-02-21', N'B', N'Credit', 30)
    ,   (4,N'2024-03-01', N'A', N'Cash', 100)
    ,   (9,N'2024-03-10', N'A', N'Cash', 10)
    ,   (8,N'2024-03-19', N'B', N'Credit', 80)
    ,   (7,N'2024-04-30', N'B', N'Cash', 150)
    ,   (6,N'2024-04-30', N'C', N'Credit', 10)
    ,   (5,N'2024-04-30', N'C', N'Cash', 10)
    ,   (10,N'2024-05-20', N'C', N'Credit', 30)
    ,   (15,N'2024-05-21', N'C', N'Credit', 10)
    ,   (12,N'2024-05-30', N'C', N'Cash', 40)
    ,   (13,N'2024-06-01', N'D', N'Credit', 40)
    ,   (14,N'2024-06-01', N'D', N'Credit', 30)
    ,   (16,N'2024-06-01', N'D', N'Cash', 40)
    ,   (24,N'2024-07-03', N'D', N'Cash', 10)
    ,   (130,N'2024-08-01', N'D', N'Credit', 30)
    ,   (1337,N'2024-08-03', N'D', N'Cash', 10)
) t (TransactionID, Date,Name,Type,Amount)

GO

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date) AS sort
    FROM    #t t
    WHERE   t.Type = 'Credit'
    )
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT  *
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date) AS sort
    FROM    #t t
    WHERE   t.Type = 'Cash'
    )
,   CTE3 AS (
    SELECT  debit.sort
    ,   debit.Name
    ,   CASE WHEN debitLeft = 1 THEN credit.Amount ELSE debit.Amount END AS amountWithdrawn
    ,   CASE WHEN debitLeft = 1 THEN debit.Amount - credit.Amount END AS amountLeft
    ,   CASE WHEN debitLeft = 1 THEN NULL ELSE credit.Amount - debit.Amount END AS creditLeft
    ,   CASE WHEN debitLeft = 1 THEN debit.sort ELSE debit.sort + 1 END AS nextSort
    ,   credit.sort AS prevCreditSort
    ,   CASE WHEN debitLeft = 1 THEN credit.sort + 1 ELSE credit.sort END AS nextCreditSort
    ,   credit.Date AS lastProcessedDate
    ,   debit.Date AS lastDebitedDate
    ,   debitleft
    ,   debit.TransactionID AS debitID
    ,   credit.TransactionID AS creditID
    FROM    CTE2 debit
    INNER JOIN CTE credit
        ON  credit.Name = debit.Name
        AND credit.Date <= debit.Date
        AND credit.sort = 1
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN debit.Amount > credit.Amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS debitLeft
            ) d
        WHERE   debit.sort = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  debit.sort
        ,   debit.Name
        ,   CASE WHEN d.debitLeft = 1 THEN cr.Amount ELSE ISNULL(prev.amountLeft, debit.Amount) END AS amountWithdrawn
        ,   CASE WHEN d.debitLeft = 1 THEN ISNULL(prev.amountLeft, debit.Amount) - cr.Amount END AS amountLeft
        ,   CASE WHEN d.debitLeft = 1 THEN NULL ELSE cr.Amount - ISNULL(prev.amountLeft, debit.Amount) END AS creditLeft
        ,   CASE WHEN d.debitLeft = 1 THEN debit.sort ELSE debit.sort + 1 END AS nextSort
        ,   credit.sort
        ,   CASE WHEN d.debitLeft = 1 THEN credit.sort + 1 ELSE credit.sort END AS nextSort
        ,   credit.Date AS lastProcessedDate
        ,   debit.Date
        ,   d.debitleft
        ,   debit.TransactionID AS debitID
    ,   credit.TransactionID AS creditID
        FROM    CTE2 debit
        INNER JOIN CTE3 prev
            ON  prev.nextSort = debit.sort
            AND prev.Name = debit.Name
        INNER JOIN CTE credit
            ON  credit.Name = debit.Name
            AND credit.Date <= debit.Date
            AND credit.sort = prev.nextCreditSort
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN prevCreditSort = nextCreditSort THEN prev.creditLeft ELSE credit.Amount END AS amount
            ) cr
        CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNULL(prev.amountLeft, debit.Amount) > cr.Amount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS debitLeft
            ) d
    ) 
SELECT  *
INTO    #transactionLog
FROM    CTE3
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

-- Update base table (credit)
UPDATE  t
SET AmountLeft = Amount - ISNULL(amountWithdrawn, 0)
FROM    #t t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  SUM(amountWithdrawn) AS amountWithdrawn
    FROM    #transactionLog l
    WHERE   l.creditID = t.TransactionID
    ) l
WHERE   t.type = 'Credit'

-- Update base table (Cash)
UPDATE  t
SET AmountLeft = t.Amount -ISNULL(l.AmountLeft, 0)
FROM    #t t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  SUM(amountWithdrawn) AS AmountLeft
    FROM    #transactionLog l
    WHERE   l.debitID = t.TransactionID
    ) l
WHERE   t.type = 'Cash'

-- Check transactions
SELECT  *
FROM    #transactionLog
ORDER BY Name, nextCreditSort, sort

-- Final result
SELECT  *
FROM    #t
ORDER BY Name, Date
```

Basically, what this does is to create two sides of a transaction, credit and cash (or debit). I sort these transactions by dates and then match them together by this sort column.
If cash check is fully covered, I increment the cash side of the sort column, so next check is processed. If similarily the credit is covered by the check, then the credit sort is incremented.
It's important to keep track if previous row's amount wasn't fully taken which i do both on credit and debit side.

Finally we get a list of all Cash -> Credit transactions, which can be used to update how much money was taken/used.

A couple of caveats:

- I don't care if cash check has less date than credit
- I strongly suggest you to create a new amount column which is used for cashflow and not overwrite original amount column, because you then lose the information about what was actually paid / credited.

Comment: Thank you, this works efficiently. As you mentioned I don't have unique dates, but I do have a unique transaction ID for each row. I will try to implement this into the update code.

Comment: Hello again, I tried emphasizing transaction ID's to the code. In my original table, I have a unique ID for each row. When I tried to use this ID it messes up the result. As you mentioned, I don't have unique dates and this causes all the problems. But I couldn't quite understand why joining by the unique transaction ID of each row instead of the date gives me wrong answer. Any suggestion on how can I move past this?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you use this ID :) The way this is done, you need to track both debit and credit ID so you are updating correct rows. I'll try to update the script to visualize these concepts

Comment: added another version which uses transactionID as concept to handle matching updates

Comment: thank you for all your efforts! It works exactly the way I needed it now.

Comment: Great. I'm a bit worried about these lines: AND credit.Date <= debit.Date, maybe you could have some cases where cash comes before credit. This stuff is tricky, but it might work better without that selection in those cases, i'm not sure